# Able to identify outlier in R but when I attempt to remove it is not getting deleted

Tags: r, data-cleaning

So I am working with a data set and I am trying to remove an outlier row from my data. The value is 123 for an employment length. There were some other outliers I had removed and that worked fine. I created a new data set that updates the previous data set just without the data set. Original data set is named credit.

Here is my code:

```
# Outlier cutoff  for annual income (Bigger than Q3 + 1.5*IQR)
outlier_annual_inc <- quantile(credit$person_income, 0.75) + 1.5*IQR(credit$person_income)
outliers <- which(credit$person_income > outlier_annual_inc)
hist(no_outlier_data$person_income, 50, xlab = "annual income", main = "Person Income")
#Outlier cutoff for age
outlier_age <- which(credit$person_age > 122)
outlier_emp_length <- which(credit$person_emp_length > 100)
outlier_emp_length
outlier_age
clean_data <- (credit[-outlier_age, ])
clean_data <- clean_data[-outliers, ]
clean_data <- clean_data[-outlier_emp_length, ]
```

When you view the clean_data it remove the age outliers and the income outliers, but not the employment length outlier (outlier_emp_length) and I am wondering why.

Comment: Are the employment length outliers common to the age and income outliers?

Comment: It would be much easier to help If you posted some data, including the outliers

Comment: How do I post the data? Just a screenshot?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).